# Simple java lib for text templating?

Tags: java, templates, text

I need to template some email texts. Nothing fancy, just replace something like `@name@` with real value. No pictures, no fancy formatting etc.

What java lib could you recommend? The simplier the better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can give [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) a shot.  I've used both in email templating engines.  They provide simple syntax for basic use cases, but you can get pretty complex later on!

Of the two, I personally prefer Freemarker because they've done a really good job of providing all sorts of different builtins that make formatting numbers and text very simple.

Answer (score 18):

A library-free alternative to the libraries already suggested: [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

Answer (score 14):

[StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) is another option. The [five-minute introduction](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/introduction.md) gives some basic examples and syntax.

```
StringTemplate hello = new StringTemplate("Hello, $name$",
                                          DefaultTemplateLexer.class);
hello.setAttribute("name", "World");
System.out.println(hello.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Try Apache Velocity or FreeMarker, they can be helpful, for me I am using FreeMarker

Answer (score 2):

It very simple to do it yourself:

```
public class Substitution {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String a = "aaaa@bbb@ccc";

    // This can be easiliy FileReader or any Reader
    Reader sr = new StringReader(a);

    // This can be any Writer (ie FileWriter)
    Writer wr = new StringWriter();

    for (;;) {
      int c = sr.read();
      if (c == -1) { //EOF
        break;
      }
      if (c == '@') {
        String var = readVariable(sr);
        String val = getValue(var);
        wr.append(val);
      }
      else {
        wr.write(c);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * This finds the value from Map, or somewhere
   */
  private static String getValue(String var)  {
    return null;
  }

  private static String readVariable(Reader sr)throws Exception {
    StringBuilder nameSB = new StringBuilder();
    for (;;) {
      int c = sr.read();
      if (c == -1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("premature EOF.");
      }
      if (c == '@') {
        break;
      }
      nameSB.append((char)c);
    }
    return nameSB.toString();
  }
}
```

You have to polish it a little bit, but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, Apache's Velocity is a good call for embedded situations.

If you want a stand-alone product, you can also use Apache's Ant.  It reduces the template within a copy task by applying substitution filters.